Characterizing Generators in Infinite Cyclic Group
Let $G = \langle a \rangle = \{ \ldots, a^{-1}, e, a, a^2, \ldots \}$ be a cyclic group of infinite order. Then:
The element $a^z$ generates $G$ if and only if $z = 1$ or $z = -1$.
I'm working on this problem.
attempt: If $a^z$ generates $G$ and $|\langle a \rangle| = |G| = \infty$, then $a^z = a$ or $a^z = a^{-1}$. Hence, I can conclude that $z = 1$ or $z = -1$. However, upon reconsideration, stating that $a^z = a$ would presuppose that $|G|$ is finite. How can I solve the problem using the fact that all powers of $a$ are distinct, i.e., $a^m = a^n \iff m = n$? Assuming that $f$ is an isomorphism (I had proved this assertion).

If $z \geq 2$, then any product of powers of $a^z$ must have an exponent that's a multiple of $z$, which means the exponent can't be $1$ or $-1$.  Thus, neither $a$ nor $a^{-1}$ can be in $\langle a^z \rangle$.  If $a^n=a^m$ for $n \lt m$, then multiplying both sides by $a^{-n}$ yields $e=a^{m-n}$, which can't happen because it would mean that $\vert G \vert = \vert \langle a \rangle \vert \leq m-n$.

'Assuming that $f$ is an isomorphism': what is $f$? Is it $\Bbb Z\to G,k\mapsto a^k$? 'I had proved this assertion': not sure to understand: did you already prove it? 'stating that $a^z = a$ would presuppose that $|G|$ is finite': why? and if this finiteness is 'presupposed', how can you 'state $a^z = a$'?

If $a^z$ generates $G$ then $a=(a^z)^k=a^{zk}$ for some $k\in\Bbb Z$, hence (" using the fact that all powers of $a$ are distinct, i.e., $a^m = a^n \iff m = n$ ") $1=zk$, which implies $z=\pm1$.
